# How to know if there are stability/ compatibility issues with enabling intel(R) speedstep

Tags: power-supply, power-management, multi-core, intel-pentium

There is this power-saving app called granola. And it requires enabling Intel(R) speedStep on the bios(CPU Configuration).

1. How would I know if there are issues with enabling this feature with my power supply?
2. Can this feature destroy the components inside my computer if it has compatibility issues with the power supply?

os: Windows 7

Comment: i am continually retagging your questions.  please try to stick to tags that already exist, instead of making up your own.  use the drop-down autocomplete list to help find existing, popular tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

speedStep can only **under**-clock your CPU, so in theory it shouldn't damage anything except your performance.

On mobile computers there are [reports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318682/EN-US/) of problems with bad-quality movie display, which can be fixed by configuring the power options.

You may find some more info on [Bay Wolf's Speedstep FAQ](http://www.bay-wolf.com/speedstep.htm) or on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep).